# Java timer that starts when you click space, ends after clicking space again

Tags: java, swing, timer, countdown, key-bindings

I am trying to program a Rubiks cube timer. Once you click space I want the timer to countdown from 15 seconds, once the 15 seconds is over, start counting up from 0. When you are done solving the cube you click space again, stopping the timer (I want the timer to count to the nearest hundredth). Here is what I have now:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;


public class CubeMain extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    CubeMain frame = new CubeMain();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public CubeMain() {

        setTitle("Cube Timer");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 600, 490);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        final JLabel Timerlbl = new JLabel("");
        Timerlbl.setBounds(269, 219, 46, 14);
        contentPane.add(Timerlbl);
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                Timerlbl.setText("Label Change");

            }
        });
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

    }
}
```

Comment: Consider using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) over KeyListener to solve possible focus issues

Answer (score 2):

So you know you need some kind of timer. The timer you want for a Swing program is a `javax.swing.Timer`. This is the basic constructor

```
Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener);
```

Where, delay is the delay time between fired actions, and the listener is what listens for those timer action events being fired each interval. A basic implementation would me something like this

```
public TimerPanel() {
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // do something
        }
    });
    timer.start();
}
```

What you could do is have a `count` variable that you increment and use to set the `timerLabel`. Then just set your key binding for the SPACE to `timer.start()` or `timer.stop()`

Take a look at this, it has the timer. It's pretty much what you need

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.Action;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class TimerPanel{

    double count = 15.00;
    boolean reverse = true;
    boolean started = false;

    private JLabel timerLabel = new JLabel(String.format("%.2f", count));
    private Timer timer;

    public TimerPanel() {
        timerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        timerLabel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(timerLabel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);


        timer = new Timer(10, new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (reverse && count > 0) {
                    count -= 0.01;
                    timerLabel.setText(String.format("%.2f", count));
                    if (count <= 0) {
                        reverse = false;
                    }
                }
                if (!reverse){
                    count += 0.01;
                    timerLabel.setText(String.format("%.2f", count));
                }
            }
        });

        Action spaceAction = new AbstractAction() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!started) {
                    timer.start();
                    started = true;
                } else {
                    timer.stop();
                    count = 15.00;
                    started = false;
                    reverse = true;
                }
            }
        };

        InputMap inputMap = timerLabel.getInputMap(JPanel.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap actionMap = timerLabel.getActionMap();

        inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("SPACE"), "spaceAction");
        actionMap.put("spaceAction", spaceAction);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                new TimerPanel();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for [*Minimal, Complete, Valid Example*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and `Action`. Minor nits: use `@Override` to validate signatures; re-factor a default value for `count`.