# Timer Task Only Runs Once

Tags: java, sockets, timer, task

How do I make my Timer Task run more than once?  This is really bothering me..

```
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.schedule(new Client(), 1000);

    public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("sent data");
        socketOut.write(0);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // disconnect client on their side
        Game.destroyGame();
        timer.cancel();
        timer.purge();
    }
}
```

I want this timer to run for an infinite amount of time until the Exception occurs.

Comment: Any luck with reading Javadoc?

Answer (score 3):

When the Javadoc says that it repeats with a specific delay, the delay is the initial delay before the `TimerTask` starts and not for how long the `TimerTask` will run. You can repeat the task every `period` milliseconds. Look at the `schedule` method. Below is a simple example that repeats every 2 seconds, **indefinitely**. In the example, the call:

```
timer.schedule(new RemindTask(seconds), 0, seconds * 1000);
```

tells `timer` to run the `RemindTask` every `seconds` seconds (*1000 because the time here is really in miliseconds), with an initial delay of 0 - i.e. start the RemindTask **right away** and then keep repeating at regular intervals.

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Main {
    static Timer timer;
    static int i = 0;

    class RemindTask extends TimerTask {

        private int seconds;

    public RemindTask(int seconds) {
        this.seconds = seconds;
    }

    public void run() {
        i+= seconds ;
        System.out.println(i + " seconds!");
    }
}

public Main(int seconds) {
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new RemindTask(seconds), 0, seconds * 1000);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new Main(2);
    System.out.format("Task scheduled.%n");
}
}
```

Comment: I looked at the javadoc for the schedule method "schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period) 
          Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified delay."... but I want it to run forever not for a certain amount of time.

Comment: See my updated answer. You can make tasks run "forever" with the `schedule()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like to me you're running a GUI program (I'm assuimg SWING, because your other question you were using SWING). So here's a bit of advice. Use a `javax.swing.Timer` for Swing program.

> "How do I make my Timer Task run more than once? "

`javax.swing.Timer` has methods `.stop()` and `.start()` and `.restart()`. A basic implementation of the `Timer` object is something like this

```
Timer timer = new Timer(delay, new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
    }
});
timer.start();
```

You can do anything you want in the `actionPerformed` and it will fire an event every how many ever milliseconds you provide to the `delay`.  You can have a button call `.start()` or `.stop()`

See [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21058016/2587435) for a simple implementation of `Timer` imitating a sort of stop watch for a Boggle game